# Google Search Domain property gets less traffic

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

I have a website that I've added as a domain property on Google Search Console - I previously just had the http and https versions set up.

The domain property is getting fewer impressions and hits than the https property. For example, a few days ago the https property tracked 19 clicks in a day while the domain property tracked only 11. How is this possible? Shouldn't the domain property always report at least as much as the http and https properties?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.